# ember-cli-broccoli fails with EEXIST ... tmp/.DS_STORE

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I've been running into this issue all day whenever I would save a file (*.hbs, *.js) locally while running `ember serve` and couldn't figure out what the deal was:

```
The Broccoli Plugin: [broccoli-persistent-filter:Babel > [Babel: ember-inflector]: Babel: ember-inflector] failed with:

Error: EEXIST: file already exists, symlink 
'/Users/myusername/Documents/my-project/tmp/broccoli_persistent_filterbabel__babel_ember_inflector-input_base_path-tS9AnlNw.tmp/.DS_Store'
-> 
'/Users/myusername/Documents/my-project/tmp/broccoli_persistent_filterbabel__babel_ember_inflector-output_path-6LGruFFD.tmp/.DS_Store'
```

I tried `rm -rf tmp` I tried cleaning everything, restarting my Text Editor (Atom) I searched all over the internet...

Answer (score 0):

After searching all day for a solution **I closed my finder window** and the problem stopped..

So apparently just close Finder on OSX and it will fix the problem. Hopefully this saves some other poor soul from wasting as much time as I did